# Small Ficus standard root issues?

Tags: roots, ficus

I have 2 small ficus standards about 3 feet height. The leaves are shaped into balls. If I continue to keep the ball of leaves small (about 1.5 to 2 feet diameter) by regular pruning will this control the growth of invasive roots from spreading?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I think you need to cut the roots every year.  We used to control our clumping bamboo this way by chopping off the runners (that were getting away) in the ground.  This is supported by this article.

[How to Control Ficus Tree Roots? Complete Guide](https://backyardlord.com/how-to-control-ficus-tree-roots/)

Quote

> Their roots can grow aggressively, causing damage to sidewalks, driveways, and foundation walls. If you’re having trouble controlling the roots of your ficus tree, there are a few things you can do.
>
> - The roots of a ficus tree are very strong and can easily damage concrete or other surfaces they come into contact with
> - If you want to control the roots of your ficus tree, you will need to prune them regularly
> - You can use a sharp knife or pruning shears to cut away any roots that are growing where you don’t want them to
> - Be sure to make clean cuts and avoid damaging the main root system
> - Regular pruning will help keep the roots under control and prevent them from causing damage to your property

**Ultimately, my suggestion is to put it in a pot and bury most of the pot.**